# pdb with multiprocessing application

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am trying to debug a python application with pdb and cant seem to get it working properly when used on sections that employ multiprocessing. I want to circumvent the cumbersome set_trace() command and am wondering if there is maybe a flag that I can pass to the invocation of the pdb command that enables multiprocessing support. Does anyone know how to do that?